# how to read xml data in IE browser using jquery Ajax function

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax

I need to read xml data using jquery in AJAX function, which is working fine in firefox... however i am stuck with IE browser... I am not able to read xml. program is required to read "proptype" from xml file. I have place alert alert(theXml) but is not giving me answer in IE however it is working in firefox browser

here is my code ..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>

 <script src="../scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="../scripts/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

 <script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        testXml();

    });


    function testXml() {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'XML_estatesIT_op4.xml',
            dataType: ($.browser.msie) ? "text" : "xml",
            success: function (xml) {

                theXml = parseXml(xml);

                alert(theXml);

                $(theXml).find("property").each(function () {

                    var b1 = $(this).find('proptype').text();

                    alert(b1);                        
                });
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("An error occurred while processing XML file.");
            }
         });
    }

   function parseXml(xml) {

        if (jQuery.browser.msie) {
            var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
            xmlDoc.async = false;
            xmlDoc.loadXML(xml);
            xml = xmlDoc;
        }

        return xml;
    }

   </script>
 </head>
 <body>

 </body>
</html>
```

=====XML=====

```
<properties>
   <property>
  <propcode>DEMO1_000001</propcode>
  <address6>Cambridgeshire</address6>
  <postcode>PE28 2BG</postcode>
  <ccode>UK</ccode>
  <priceask>360,000</priceask>
  </property>
</properties>
```

Comment: There is no reason why you should do anything different for IE. Set the content type with jQuery so it loads the XML correctly and the data should be the xml document. [And you xml document does not appear to be 100% valid. Missing a line.

Comment: this above code is working with all major browser except IE browser...  and i am calling parseXML function to modify data to deal or compatible with IE as I have come across; IE browser doesn't support direct xml file!!! I have change xml document (http://www.w3schools.com/xml/cd_catalog.xml) to find titles of all CD in following xml file ... and IE still not reading data ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I have found the solution, the trick is use separate code XML for IE browsers that are version of less than 10 .

so every time Ajax is call a method parseXml is called with input parameter XML Dom or text, depending on browser .... and if current browser is IE, it upload XML doc, process it according to Microsoft standards and return XML and rest of processes in Ajax carries on as expected!!

note : browser.msie is not supported in jQuery 1.9 but you can add jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js in order to make it compatible or use userAgent and find which is current browser

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'XML_file.xml',
  dataType: ($.browser.msie) ? "text" : "xml",
  success: function (xml) {

     var processedXML = parseXml(xml);

     $(processedXML).find('my record').each(function () {  //code  } 
  });


 function parseXml(xml) {

  if ($.browser.msie)  {

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
   else {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "XML_file.xml", false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;

    xml = xmlDoc;
  }
        return xml;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 function parseXML(xml) {
    if (jQuery.browser.msie) {
        alert("dd3");
        var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        xmlDoc.loadXML(xml);
        xml = xmlDoc;
    }
    alert("dd4");
    return xml;
}

function searchThis() {
    alert("dd1");
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: XMLSource,
        dataType: ($.browser.msie) ? "text" : "xml",
        success: function (xml) {
            alert("dd2");
            var newXML = parseXML(xml);
            loadPublication(newXML)
        }
    });
}
```

enjoy with this working for IE.

Comment: i pass all way down to alert("dd4") but i am getting error:
Error: The value of the property 'loadPublication' is null or undefined, not a Function object

Comment: alert is just for testing that up to where you reached in code

Comment: set the value of URL here i use XMLSource as global variable where xml file path is stored. u can do same or just pass the path of ur xml file on which u want to work.

Answer (score 1):

You no need to repeat the xml file name and do the same operations again in parseXML unnecessarily.

The trick here is to disable the caching. But still IE sometimes doesn't disable caching. Hence add the timestamp as a query string along with your xml file name in the url which solves the problem. I tested it and worked 100% on IE and other browsers.

```js
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: "XML_file.xml?timestamp=" + new Date().getTime(),   // add the timestamp to the url to avoid caching in IE
  dataType: ($.browser.msie) ? "text" : "xml",
  cache: "false",
  success: function (xml) {

     var processedXML = parseXml(xml);

     $(processedXML).find('my record').each(function () {  //code  } 
  }
});

function parseXml(xml) {
   if (jQuery.browser.msie) {    // Only for IE
      var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
      xmlDoc.async="false";
      xmlDoc.loadXML(xml);
      xml = xmlDoc;
   }
   return xml;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i manage problem with chrome by adding chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files to its property target location but not getting for IE. please any one can then post your answer.

Comment: i almost have enough, it seems Microsoft make it so difficult purposely to implement so simple thing or i am dumb... i don't know... i am wondering if i can convert XML data to JSON before process ???