# Different behavior for empty XML response between IE and Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using jQuery to read an XML file. Sometimes the XML is empty, and I expect the error function (`no_info`) is executed because the file is not formatted according to the `dataType`.

In IE 10 the Error function is executed. But in Firefox (40.0.2) the success function (`parse`) is executed. Why both browsers behave differently and which one is correct?

```js
$.ajax({
  url: '/~play/shout.xml',
  dataType: "xml",
  success: parse,
  error: no_info
});
```

Comment: IE being IE, did you try it without the '~'? I just gave up on it.. when my team develops websites/services, we always put that jumbotron up there with "get yourself some chrome/firefox" message.

Comment: I think this is happening because there might be an unescaped character or new line character in the file, where browsers interpret them differently. Can you check your xml to see if there is a newline? If so remove it and try again.

Comment: No NemanjaT thats not the problem. The xml file read correct. I can read the nodes from the file. But when the XML file is empty, Firefox goes tot the parse function and IE goes to the no_info function. And thats strange....

Comment: Ok afrin216 thanks, there is a newline in the file. But I expected that when there are no nodes both browsers goes to the no_info function.

Comment: Welcome to the world of cross-browser-compatibility-pain :)

Comment: I believe that XML response should never be empty. At least a header must be present. (<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>)

Comment: Can you post the empty response from your $.ajax call.

Comment: Can you please post the error

Comment: If I were you, I'd set the callback to console.log(response) for success and failure... then I'd see what the difference was. Also I'd look in the network tab to see what the response headers are.

Comment: How about adding: `nocontent:no_info`? Why so many upvotes for some cryptic question with so litte info provided? To explore the sick mind of IE programmers?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there's a [bug in IE](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-ajax-doesn-t-return-xml-with-internet-explorer-10)

how about you handle it yourself?

```
 function parseXml(xml) {

   if ($.browser.msie)  {

   if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
     xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   }else {// code for IE6, IE5
     xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
   xmlhttp.open("GET", "XML_file.xml", false);
   xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;

xml = xmlDoc;
} 
return xml;
```

}

[previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035794/how-to-read-xml-data-in-ie-browser-using-jquery-ajax-function)

Answer (score 1):

which JQuery version do you use? I use the most actual and with my ajax function I couldn't encounter any issues. That's my code

```
function sync(arg, callback){   //ajax result 
    $('.loader').show();
    $.ajax({ 
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'liveSearch.php',
        data: arg, // send argument and update
        success: function(data, status, xhr){
         $('.loader').hide();
         callback(data);
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            console.log(thrownError);
        }
   });  
}

function onCallback(data) {
        result = data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

dataType parameter merely indicates what "Content-Type" header you are expecting.
As long as the file exists and served with a valid Content-Type Success function should be triggered.

Answer (score 0):

instead of  just `/~` try passing the whole URL from which you want to retrieve the XML file.