# XML IE11 - Can't Extract Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, internet-explorer-11

So I'm trying to extract data from and XML file using jQuery and everything is working well on Chrome and Firefox and like usual there's a problem with IE. I looked up the answers here on stackoverflow and one seemed like it's working but still returning undefined.

I'm getting the file using ajax. Here is how I'm doing it:

```
$('<div>' + xml + '</div>').find('videoNews');
```

Now I look in the dev console and I keep getting `context: undefined`.

In Chrome or FF, I do it this way and it's working fine as expected:

```
$(xml).find('videoNews');
```

Anyone has a solution to that frustrating problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So the answer is: [how to read xml data in IE browser using jquery Ajax function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035794/how-to-read-xml-data-in-ie-browser-using-jquery-ajax-function).

Using the function `parseXml(xml)` you can read the xml file.

Then the trick to get the content from the XML file is to do the following:

```
$(videoDescription).find('shortHeadline')[0].textContent;
```

In other browsers if not IE, you should do the following:

```
$(videoDescription).find('shortHeadline')[0].innerHTML;
```

Hope this helps someone who is in the same position.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and scoured the internet and also found that `.innerHTML` doesn't work in IE11 and also that it's a quasi hack anyway since it shouldn't be used to read XML nodes.

I didn't like the idea of using different solutions depending on what browser I am using but those are most of the solutions I found. However, one guy on youtube suggested to use `.firstChild.data` to read a given node. I've implemented that in my own project and it seems to be working fine. I don't know why this method isn't used and suggested more.

Comment: I found that  $(...).find(...).text() works in any browser,